# REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event isn't triggered on FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

I need a little help here since my code doesn't work and I can't find where I'm failing. See this is the function I'm using to register users on my application (taked from [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php) and changed a bit to suite my needs):

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $entity = new SysUsuario();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UsuarioType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $user_data = $request->get('user_register');
    $profile_data = $request->get('user_register')['perfil'];

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $user->setUsername($profile_data['persJuridica'] . $profile_data['rif']);
        $user->setEmail($user_data['email']);
        $user->setPlainPassword($user_data['password']);

        $role = $profile_data['roleType'];
        if ($role === "O") {
            $user->addRole("ROLE_OPERADOR");
        }
        elseif ($role === "CH") {
            $user->addRole("ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO");
        }

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $profile = new SysPerfil();
        $profile->setPersJuridica($profile_data['persJuridica']);
        $profile->setRif($profile_data['rif']);

        $ci = isset($profile_data['ci']) ? $profile_data['ci'] : null;
        if ($ci != NULL) {
            $profile->setCi($profile_data['ci']);
        }

        $profile->setNombre($profile_data['nombre']);
        $profile->setApellido($profile_data['apellido']);
        $profile->setRoleType($profile_data['roleType']);
        $profile->setUser($user);

        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }
    else {
        $errors = $this->getFormErrors($formProfile);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array('status' => true, 'errors' => $errors));
}
```

The problem here is that my code is never triggering the [REGISTRATION_SUCCESS](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/6fc28e41805868c6c635de12266c40595c2e7ce8/EventListener/EmailConfirmationListener.php) event so I didn't get any email and  therefore I can't confirm users, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you overriding RegistrationController? is the registerAction() function triggered? is the form valid?

Comment: @tttony the answer to all your question is "yes"

Comment: do you enabled email confirmation?

Comment: @tttony yes, it's enabled as explained in docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dig and dig deeper in my code I found where the problem was. Thanks to @tttony user who turns on the bulb, I, accidentally, delete the `confirmation` configuration at `config.yml` and for that reason the event never was triggered, so the easy solution:

```
fos_user:
    ....
    registration:
        confirmation:
            from_email:
                address:        admin@local.com
                sender_name:    Myself
```

Now before found the previous solution I come with another one, which made me study and learn and I leave here too:

```
 /** Disable the user by default - this is done in the event */
 $user->setEnabled(false);

/** @var $mailer FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface */
$mailer = $this->container->get('fos_user.mailer');

if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
     $user->setConfirmationToken($str->generateRandomString(32));
}

$mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);

$session = new Session();
$session->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
```

The only thing I wont be able to do here was use the `FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface` I don't know how to, so if any knows I'll be grateful if leave the answer to that one, both solutions works since I tested.